# Yubikey security key for file based container

Tags: encryption, yubikey

Does anyone have a solution for using the Yubikey Security Key as a second factor for file-based crypto containers like VeraCrypt or something else? I know the Security Key doesn't allow PGP, but now I don't have another key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you're on Linux.

Short answer, from the top of my head: should be no problem.

LUKS can be used to create encrypted files, then you can put a file system in there, and mount the result. Something like the following (untested!):

```bash
CONTAINER=yans-encrypted-image-file
DEVICENAME=yans-volume
fallocate -l 10G "$CONTAINER"
cryptsetup luksFormat "$CONTAINER"
sudo cryptsetup  luksOpen "$CONTAINER" "$DEVICENAME"
sudo mkfs.xfs "/dev/mapper/$DEVICENAME"
# Now ready to mount, e.g. via
udisksctl mount -b "/dev/mapper/$DEVICENAME"
# To close:
udisksctl unmount -b "/dev/mapper/$DEVICENAME"
sudo cryptsetup close "$DEVICENAME"
```

There's plenty of guides out there on how to enroll your Yubikey as LUKS secret provider. How packaging for such things works: sadly kind of depends on your Linux distro, so I'll have to let you research that on your own.